# I want to create a scrollable dialog box?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a vertical scrollbar to an AlertDialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564867/adding-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-an-alertdialog-in-android)

In my project, there is some button.Whenever I click on one button ,it shows a alert dialog box with the description of that button.i have wrote description in string.xml with . whenever i click the button, it fetch the description from string.xml and shows us.But my problem is that my message( which will show in dialog box)is too long.so,i want scrollable alertdialog box.with out creating another xml file with, how is it possible in java code.

Comment: Hi, you need to make custom dialog box for this. You should create one XML. And write that Textview inside ScrollView. Ask me if you need any help.

Comment: Custom dialog with layout having ScrollView is the option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564867/adding-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-an-alertdialog-in-android

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33098898/1881527

Answer (score 1):

You are able to customize the dialog box by using the setView method and apply a custom view to the dialog box.

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  ad.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
  ad.setTitle("Instructions ...");
  **ad.setView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.instructions_dialog,null));**

  ad.setPositiveButton("OK", 
    new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
      // OK, go back to Main menu
     }
    }
   );

   ad.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
     // OK, go back to Main menu   
    }}
   );
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Love how people just copy answers and not flag questions as duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564867/adding-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-an-alertdialog-in-android

Answer (score 0):

this is an example.you can change according to your requirement

you can add this on button event

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
Spinner spin = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
Spinner spin2 = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
EditText t1 =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText t2 =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText t3 =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText t4 =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
dialog.show();
```

alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/widget54"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="211dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="10dp"
    android:layout_y="11dp"
     >

</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="208dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="19dp"
    android:layout_y="76dp"
   />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="208dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="20dp"
    android:layout_y="138dp"
  />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="212dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="18dp"
    android:layout_y="196dp"
    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="5dp"
    android:layout_y="254dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="310dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```