# Android - How do I make this alert dialog scrollable?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am a beginner in android and making my first android app. my 'About' menu item, when clicked shows an AlertDialog with a really long message.
I have been trying different methods to make it scrollable but I couldn't. I have tried reading different questions on StackOverflow but they didn't work for me. Here is my AlertDialog code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");  
alertDialog.setMessage("Here is a really long message.");  
alertDialog.setButton("OK", null);  
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

Can anybody explain to me in detail how to make it scrollable?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html if you need a more complex view than a text, you have to do it a bit differently, using a scrollable TextView e.g. seehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Comment: use like that http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a vertical scrollbar to an AlertDialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564867/adding-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-an-alertdialog-in-android)

Comment: This is the perfect answer for this without using a new layout https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098898/2462531

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This solution is take from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564867/adding-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-an-alertdialog-in-android).

In order for a view to scrollable, it must be nested inside of a ScrollView container:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
        <TextView />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note that a ScrollView container can only have one child layout view. It is not possible, for example, to place a TextView and Button in a ScrollView without the LinearLayout.

Comment: I guess with scrollview you typically need to set the width/height; as in the example in the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352987/scrollable-textview-inside-alertdialog-android

Comment: This is the easiest solution ! thanks ! works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 13):

In that situation you can create your own layout.xml file containing a Text View under Scroll View. and set TextMessage in this Text View, Inflate this layout with your alert dialog box.

yourxmlfile.xml

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In Activity Class

```
LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxmlfile, null);

TextView textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
textview.setText("Your really long message.");
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");  
//alertDialog.setMessage("Here is a really long message.");
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", null);  
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Use your id of your xml TextView here, what you given id of textView in`<TextView  android:id="@+id/textmsg"'

Comment: I got to fix that. This line was in need of modification..
 (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);

Comment: Never mind i got it worked after a few changes sorry for my comment above i can edit it :(

Comment: @cutiko look the answer again, there is only one direct child view `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

**Android Scrollable AlertDialog**

You can just use a default approach:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title").setMessage(message);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

You can notice that a message TextView is built-in ScrollView container in `alert_dialog.xml`. It is a layout that is used.

The location of `alert_dialog.xml`

```
<some_path>/Android/sdk/platforms/android-<version>/data/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml
//e.g.
/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/data/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it programmatically.  This is especially helpful if you want a non-standard dialog box.  (e.g. in the below example, I want to add a EditText field in addition to my message.)  You can also add buttons, as normal.

```
final ScrollView myScroll = new ScrollView(this);
        final TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setText("Put really long text here.");
        myText.setPadding(30, 5, 30, 0); //or whatever you want
        final LinearLayout myView = new LinearLayout(this);
        myView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
        myView.addView(myText);
        myView.addView(input);
        myScroll.addView(myView);
        builder.setView(myScroll);
```