# Scrollview in dialog fragment is not scrolling, android?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-dialogfragment

This is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/colse"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome_to_app"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/colse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/set_up_profile"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/welcomeTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileTos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/profile_tos"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileTitle" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstNameInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileTos">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.LighterEditText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lastNameInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNameInput">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:hint="@string/last_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.LighterEditText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/centered"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/gender"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/centered"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lastNameInput" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/genderSeparator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#979797"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/centered"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gender" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/birthday"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/birthday"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/centered"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lastNameInput" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#979797"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/centered"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/birthday" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/birthdayOffer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/birthday_offer"
        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/genderSeparator" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/fitnessGoalInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/birthdayOffer">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fitnessGoal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:hint="@string/fitness_goal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.LighterEditText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/fitnessLevelInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fitnessGoalInput">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fitnessLevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:hint="@string/current_fitness_level"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.LighterEditText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typeOfClass"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/type_of_classes"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fitnessLevelInput" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/classCategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/typeOfClass" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/categorySeparator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#979797"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/classCategory" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_black_round_corner"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categorySeparator" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/app_cms_page_loading_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the java code for dialog fragment

```
public class ProfileSetupDialog extends DialogFragment {
public ProfileSetupDialog() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_setup, container);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final RelativeLayout root = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    root.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(root);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    height = height - 120;
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    return dialog;
}
```

}

I have multiple edit text on my dialog so the problem occurs is that the keyboard hides the edit text for which the user is typing and the scrollview does not scroll the dialog. Any solutions?

My activity already contains

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269565/cant-scroll-in-dialog-fragment. it feel it quite same your problem

Comment: @PhanVanLinh tried that but doesn't seems to work