# How to create a popup with a scroll view programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I need to create a popup window programmatically, with a scrollview is this possible? i need to do everything in java side.

I was using a alert dialog but maybe is better a popup window, but didn't find much information on how to do it programatically.

i was using this code for the alert dialog

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(OFActivityA.this);
        alert.setTitle("Something");
        alert.setText("fe");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //what you need to do after click "OK"
            }

        });
        alert.show();
```

Comment: This question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955053/android-how-do-i-make-this-alert-dialog-scrollable

Comment: Yeah, almost but they are using xml layout

Answer (score 0):

*i need to do everything in java side.*, not really - you can create your custom dialog with a custom layout and have any kind of layout that you would like to have.

**For example, create dialogClass:**

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog); //this is your layout for the dialog

    }
}
```

**And all you need to do to show your dialog is call those line:**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.show(); // this line shows your dialog
```

You can put all your logic into the class using java as you want to only that now you can control your layout and how it looks in easier way.