# Android scrollable AlertDialog programmatically

Tags: java, android, layout, android-alertdialog, programmatically-created

How can i programmatically make my AlertDialog Scrollable ?

My AlertDialog is defined like this :

```
private void DisplayAlertChoice(String title, String msg, final int pos)
{       
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     CheckBox[] t=new CheckBox[15];
     for (i=0;i<currentBattery.temperatureNumber;i++)
     {               
         t[i]=new CheckBox(this);
         t[i].setText("title");
         t[i].setChecked(false);
         t[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

         layout.addView(t[i]);      
     }
    alert.setView(layout);      
    alert.show();
```

}

I tried a few solutions found in the net but didn't work for me.

Can someone give me a pertinent solution to make it scrollable programmatically ?

Comment: have you tried puttin the LinearLayout into a ScrollView?

Comment: You might also want to look at [multi-choice mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)

Comment: multi-choice is cool @codeMagic

Comment: @blackbelt : i tried it, but it forces my app to stop.

Comment: Using ScrollView should work. Please post the stack trace you're getting.

Comment: @matiash : Yes it works, thank you.
My error was adding "layout" instead of "scrollView" to my alert object. alert.setView(layout);

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33098898/1881527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*i tried it, but it forces my app to stop.*

ScrollView can have just a child. It is an Android constraint. So, doing

```
    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     CheckBox[] t=new CheckBox[15];
     for (i=0;i<currentBattery.temperatureNumber;i++)
     {               
         t[i]=new CheckBox(this);
         t[i].setText("title");
         t[i].setChecked(false);
         t[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

         scrollView.addView(t[i]);      
     }
```

will make your app crash, because you are adding more than one child to the ScrollView. But if you do

```
final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 CheckBox[] t=new CheckBox[15];
 for (i=0;i<currentBattery.temperatureNumber;i++)
 {               
     t[i]=new CheckBox(this);
     t[i].setText("title");
     t[i].setChecked(false);
     t[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

     layout.addView(t[i]);      
 }
 final ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this); 
 scrollView.addView(layout);
```

it should work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks it worked. My error was adding "layout" instead of "scrollView" to my alert object.

    alert.setView(layout);

Comment: this didnt work for me at all

Comment: 8y ago it worked. API changed a lot